# If I import a module inside a function, will the variables be local?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-import

If I do an import of a module in python 3 inside a function (local scope), will the things imported be local to the function?

Like

```
def test():
    import math
    s = math.cos(1)
s = math.cos(1)
```

Comment: yes, the scope of the import will be the same of the function scope, but keep in mind that it is a good practice to import modules at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that once you import the module, even in a local scope, any changes to the module state will be preserved as the module remains loaded, it just clears local variables if it's called in local scope.

Comment: Side-note: While it is local scope, if you're considering doing this for performance (local scope is cheaper to access than enclosing, which is cheaper than global, which is cheaper than built-in scope, search "LEGB" for more info), don't. `import` does cache modules (so the second `import` doesn't actually reload), but the import machinery is fairly cumbersome/slow, even when it ends up retrieving the cached module; you'll almost certainly lose any scope related performance to the cost of the every-call import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the module will be local to the function, at least in the example above(I am using Python 3.6).

Example:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
def test():
...     import math
...     s = math.cos(1)
...
g = math.cos(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```